# Access a static variable from a service

Tags: java, android, variables, static

My application has a service and my `MainActivity` has a `static` variable :

```
public static boolean appIsPlaying = false;
```

And my service code is something like this :

```
MainActivity.appIsPlaying = false;
```

This code works well but I'm not sure that it's a true way. So, would you help me if there is a problem with this solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really agree with the people who say let's just use getters and setters for everything, and that's the solution. Your solution is simple, but effective. There are no problems with this way of communication between a service and an activity per se. This isn't some public API, so using public fields isn't a definite no-no.

Problems can only arise if you have certain requirements which you have to fulfill. This from of interaction is the simplest, therefore it can't do much. For example, if you want to listen to the event of changing the value, then you will have a problem because you just set the value and don't notify the activity.

If that's the case, then you can [bind to the service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html), and implement more complex interaction. Listening to the value changes could be done by storing listeners in the service and notifying them when changes happen.

There is not really *the* way to do it, there are more appropriate ones and less so. You have to choose one of them depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Put your static variable in a utility class and create static getters and setters with required validations. Making the class Single Instance is also preferred but what you are doing right is not without problems.

Comment: @Kermia.. what if you project has a bug and someone else who knows nothing about your implementation and sets this variable value some where else which your service uses.. it will break your code and reduces readability, and not flexible and maintainable... these are very crucial when programming..

Comment: No, That's not very important(for me at least). I wanted to know if there is a system problem. Like deadlocks, losing data or anything else?

Comment: @Kermia .. nothing related to system can happen here,.. but this is error porn for sure...